# Launch Laravel-Filemanager by a button instead of wysiwyg

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor

I have successfully integrated [laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) to my laravel project.  The docs only shows integration with either ckeditor or tinymce.  Though I successfully integrated it with ckeditor, I find that this is too much for me as I don't really need the editor.  All I need is a button that would show the filemanager when that button is clicked.

Is there any way to use standard bootstrap button to launch the filemanager instead of showing the ckeditor interface?

Comment: well, did you actually try to access ckeditor's parameter that *obviously looked like an url* manually? i bet it's the url to access the filemanager views.

Comment: i was searching the same solution. 
@Tezla the file manager view works. But could not select the file form there.

Comment: well, i didn't try it myself, but looks like the url in the integration tutorial is a ajax-based.. so, expecting it to access the file manager directly through it seems infeasible. however, i wonder when you publish laravel-filemanager's asset, did you found an iteresting view like [this](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/src/views/index.blade.php), and as i read the source it turns out the view were invoked by [this](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/src/controllers/LfmController.php#L42) so, give it a route and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it useful now or not, but you can read the "Standalone button" on [this page](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/integration).